# Powershell if/else based on repadmin results?

Tags: powershell, datadog

I'm trying to figure out how to take the results of "repadmin /syncall /d /e" and put the results into an if else statement. I've considered trying to just look for the success string it outputs for the if and, but I'm wondering if there is a more official way to pull the status code? So if successful use some built in PowerShell feature to know the status is successful. I'm doing this so I can publish a metric to DataDog giving a pass or fail count for cross-site AD Replications. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use the cmdlets? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2014/06/06/active-directory-replication-cmdlets-vs-repadmin/

Comment: That's an idea, but that article doesn't provide enough information, like for instance the question of the status I asked in my original question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$LASTEXITCODE` will give you the exit code of the last native command (executable) that was run.